# How to show a confirmation dialog in Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I have created a Lightning component that saves data into a custom object inside Salesforce. I am trying to display a confirmation dialog now. How can I show this?

ui:dialog is not yet supported in Saleforce Lightning.
ui:message does display a message but it does not give a good User Experience.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: u can use javascript / jquery or any other similar libraries to show modal dialogs

Comment: is this in S1 mobile? or on your own app?

Answer (score 6):

If this is a Lightning Component in S1 mobile and Lightning Experience Desktop, then I'd suggest just firing the `showToast` event.

This will pop a notification toast message down from the top of the UI. You want to fire it from the callback you set in the action object. It works like this:

```
action.setCallback(this, function(a){

        //check for success/failure do other processing then...

        //get the system showToast event
        var showToast = $A.get('e.force:showToast');

        //set the title and message params
        showToast.setParams(
            {
                'title': 'Progress: ',
                'message': a.state
            }
        );

        //fire the event
        showToast.fire();
```

In the end you get a message that looks like this with minimal effort:

[image: Standard toast pop-down in S1 mobile.]

There is an additional optional parameter to show the toast pop-down for longer than the default time (which 3 seconds). And another parameter to show an icon that I've not sussed out yet as [the docs](http://login.salesforce.com/auradocs) (link requires org login) for this event aren't well fleshed out.

This event *only* works in Salesforce1 Mobile, so if you're building your own app, best practice would be to implement this functionality as a component that is listening to your own custom event (just like this), and then use that component inside of the main component.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I implemented it as a Standalone app. But now I am being asked to add it to SF1 too. Will I have to implement separate components for both? I also have posted some other issues which I am facing on http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/69762/problem-in-adding-lightning-app-to-salesforce-1.

Comment: You shouldn't have to build entirely again. But there are some features/services that you will need to build yourself in your standalone app, whereas in SF 1 there are app events surfaced to provide those services, such as the confirmation toast component.

Comment: By my understanding, wouldn't your answer work regardless of whether if was SF1 or not?

Comment: When I wrote this, the `showToast` event was only available in the S1 container. I've not looked back at this for some time.